# How to re render component once store data is updated via api svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component, svelte-store

I have a svelte store where I keep some dummy data in variable named tasks. I also fetch new data with API inside the store using Axios. then push new data in tasks variable. can read proper data in component but the data from api does not render.

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import config from "../../config";
import axios from "axios";

let tasks = [
  {
    // this is what api fetches.
    id: 500,
    name: "task 500",
    status: 0,
  },
];

axios
  .get(config.API_URL + "task")
  .then(function (response) {
    response.data.tasks.forEach((task) => {
      tasks.push(task);
      tasks = tasks;
    });
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("something went wrong");
  });

// console.log(tasks);

const Tasks = writable(tasks);

export default Tasks;
```

i need to somehow how tasks list in component using automatic or manual rerender. or any other way its posible. the tasks data in component is logging fine but component view is not updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're updating `tasks` while your store is actually `Tasks` (which was initialized with your dummy data.

Changing `tasks` later on does not automatically update the store object as well.

It would be better to place the data received from your api call directly into the store object

```js
import { writable } from "svelte/store";
import config from "../../config";
import axios from "axios";

let tasks = [
  {
    // this is what api fetches.
    id: 500,
    name: "task 500",
    status: 0,
  },
];

const Tasks = writable(tasks);

axios
  .get(config.API_URL + "task")
  .then(function (response) {
    response.data.tasks.forEach((task) => {
      tasks.push(task);
    });
    
    // Update Tasks instead
    Tasks.set(tasks);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("something went wrong");
  });

export default Tasks;
```